# Get correctly path file from Linux for Java Application

Tags: java, windows, linux, filesystems, case-sensitive

I have a java application as a jar, it encrypt some files, I use a JFileChooser to get the root path, it works ok, 2 directories inside de root path contain the directories and inside of these directories a files to be encrypted   , one or many of these directories is the month ( example path/january or path/May). The JFileChooser only explore  the rooh path directory,the name of months directories are in the code of application, I have 12 monhts, the first word of month starts with uppercase, but if I have the name of directory in lowercase the appplication doesn't recognize the path, it for linux OS, in Windows works perfect. any suggestions ?

Comment: *"any suggestions ?"*  Ensure the program does not have to deal with file names that are the same letters, but different case, to actual file names.  I do not quite understand where you are getting these issues (incorrect case file name) from, though.

Comment: I tested with correct correct path in linux and works perfect. the name of directories in Windows do not depend if is lowercase or uppercase, it works fine, in Linux have to be exactly the same letters.

Comment: Yes, most file systems are case sensitive.  Windows is not.

Comment: Yes, I realized. What could be the solution for Linux?

Comment: So what's the problem?  Use the correct case and it will work on all systems.

Comment: The problem is that the application should be flexible for names of folders.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper then handle both cases. Check if "lowercase" file exists, if it does not exist, check for the "Uppercase" file. I can't see where is the problem?

Comment: but if the name of directoy has some like this DicemBer? doesn´t work.

Comment: 1) That has nothing to do with case when you start throwing the letter 'i' into 'December' (note 3 e's, no i).  2) What on earth is making these directories?  You cannot expect to account for every case of every miss-spelling of all 12 months.  3) You can help us to help you by describing the situation that leads to this circumstance, the workflow.  It makes no sense to think your app. can guess what some directory name might exist that is similar to the name of a month.  4) Look at [`File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson, sorry is December, the name of months folder have to be well spelling, I don´t make the folders, I don´t know who will make it, but maybe when somebody create a folder could make a mistake writing the name, example (ApRil), the name of month is correct and in windows go perfect. I use this function to get the folders some part of code:  if(actualDirectorio.isDirectory()){
    ficheros = actualDirectorio.listFiles();
      
     for (File file : ficheros)... In hard code I have de months example: final String FEBRERO ="Febrero";. Final users will be Spanish people.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can figure it, what you want can be done with `equalsIgnoreCase`.  Here is crude pseudo-code based on your snippet.

```
// ...
final String FEBRERO ="Febrero";
// ...

if(actualDirectorio.isDirectory()){ 
    ficheros = actualDirectorio.listFiles(); 
    for (File file : ficheros) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            // proceed to check if it is one of the month names
            // ..
            if (file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(FEBRERO)) {
                // process Files in Febrero OR FEBRERO or febrero OR FeBrErO ..
            } else if ..
        }
    }
}
```

It would be better to encapsulate the conditions for accepting a directory as representing a month within a [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) that can be used with overloaded variants of `listFiles()`.  Batteries not included.